# which object is causing NullReferenceException

Tags: .net-2.0, windbg, sos

Dumpfile is reporting a NullReferenceException. I can see the stacktrace as which method is throwing this exception. This method itself is kind of long and doing lot of things, Is there someway I can determine which object is actually been null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NullReferenceException` indicates the *lack* of an object - there's no such thing as a null object. I assume you mean which *variable* was null, or more precisely which *expression* evaluated to null. No, there's nothing which will indicate that.

If you're using a debug build, you should get line numbers in the stack trace, which should help you to pin it down to an individual statement. If you're using a release build, you probably don't have line numbers - this is one of many reasons to keep your methods short and sweet.

Alternatively, if you're using windbg and can make it break when the exception occurs, that should give you a good indication, of course...

Comment: i was thinking there may be someway of determing which was the last instruction that ran (via !dso, !dumpil or !u or some other instruction) ???

Comment: @palmsnow: Not that I'm aware of. It's *possible* that there's a windbg-specific way of getting more information, but personally I would try to make your code more easily diagnosable to start with. If you've got an exception object which has been serialized somehow (as opposed to just converted to text) then it's *possible* there's more information available...

Answer (score 3):

!sosex.mk will give you the IL offset at the point of failure.  You can use this information in conjuction with one or more of several disassembly methods to see what is going on.  !sos.U, !sos.dumpil or !sosex.muf will disassemble the method for you and allow you to inspect the code at the failing location.  In order to find the relevant fields, locals or arguments, in optimized code, you need to use !sos.dso or !sosex.mdso to dump out the objects on the stack and in the registers and then do some investigative work.  !sosex.mdso will allow you to limit the output by number of occurrences or several filtering mechanisms.